# Writing to linux /tmp directory fails after installation on new server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, debian, passenger

I have ported my ruby on rails application to a new server. (Debian 5 -> Debian 10)

All seems to work ok but the new installation behaves strange when writing to the /tmp directory.

I made a code example:

```
    FileUtils.touch "/share/tmp/testXYZ.txt"
    FileUtils.touch "/tmp/testXYZ.txt"
```

The first line works and creates a file i can see.

The second line does not throw an error and seems to work but it does not create a (viewable?) file.

I can create a file in the /tmp manualy and i see the file.

I can create a file in the /tmp with irb (ruby) and i see the file.

All is very strange. In an other piece of code i create a file in the /tmp and use send_file to send it. All works ok. But is cannot see the file.

Seem like the files are created but not visable, or created somewhere else, or delete after creation.

Any ideas ?

The problem is on a debian vps, i run apache and passenger and ruby on rails.

Comment: Because security, tmp may be mounted only per user (do not use /tmp to exchange data between users).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  How could i check if the /tmp is mounted per user. As far as i can see this is not the case. Is the apache or passenger process responsable for this ?